# Cannot access router via ethernet cable

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ethernet

I cannot access my router's settings on any of my computers. The only way to access my router is via wi-fi. I have my router configured to use DHCP and it worked great for years. Devices can connect and router assigns ip's properly.
Every device has a default gateway automatically set to 192.168.0.1 and this is my router's ip. Also in my router's configuration I can see every device's name, mac etc. and every device has working internet connection, but anytime I want to connect to my routers configuration or if I try to ping 192.168.0.1 I get `Request timed out`.

I don't understand this, because as I said my router sees every device, and every device has default gateway 192.168.0.1 and yet the devices can't access my router. The only way to access my router's settings is via wi-fi

Answer (score 2):

> Anytime I want to connect to my routers configuration or if I try to
>   ping 192.168.0.1 I get `Request timed out.`

Depending on the manageability of your router's settings, each of your router's LAN ports, or each SSID (if your router supports multiple virtual SSIDs) can be allowed or denied to access and manage your router's control panel, as well as accessing your router using ICMP(ping) and Telnet. You can usually find these settings under **"Management"** section of your router (manufacturer dependent). However, that's unusual that you are allowed to access your router from Wi-Fi and not LAN, because they restrict manageability from WLAN by default to make it harder for someone who found your Wi-Fi password to penetrate your network.

Comment: I checked every setting and none of my lan ports are blocked. I use D-Link 655. I added static address to one of my computers and reservered it in the router to see if anything would change, but the computer still can't access default gateway even though it has internet connection.

Comment: @FCin Your router is restricting access to itself using ICMP and HTTP protocols from LAN. There must be some checkbox or something in your Local Network or Management settings that enables Manageability for that zone.

Comment: hmm... I enabled remote management and I'm able to access my router but using my WAN ip, but LAN ip (192.168.0.1) still doesn't work

Comment: You can create a user account for me and give me your address to check. I'm talking about User, Not the Admin! User is readonly and can't change settings.

Comment: However, now that I read your router's manual (if complete) there are apparently no settings related to your problem. Did you try to disable Firewall (of the router I mean)

Comment: I cannot disable firewall. I can only set DMZ that will enable all ports for a single device.

Comment: Under **Tools; ADMIN** you can set a User Password that allows someone to view your routers configuration without changing your settings. If you give me a user password plus your public IP and management port, I can check your configuration... and if you are concerned about your privacy I respect that, but unfortunately do to the difference between configurations even from the same manufacturer, it's not easy to comment on router issues.